# SpringMVC How to start a thread with start of application

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-mvc

In my springmvc application i want to start a thread for some iterative work which is going to be repeated after every 30 seconds for the life of application. where should I start this thread should I write a separate servlet for it? or should I start it in some controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [scheduler](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/04/23/4-ways-to-schedule-tasks-in-spring-3-scheduled-example/) than thread

**fixedRate** makes Spring run the task on periodic intervals even if the last invocation may be still running.

**fixedDelay** specifically controls the next execution time when the last execution finishes.

**cron** is a feature originating from Unix cron utility and has various options based on your requirements.

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay =30000)
public void demoServiceMethod () {... }

@Scheduled(fixedRate=30000)
public void demoServiceMethod () {... }

@Scheduled(cron="0 0 * * * *")
public void demoServiceMethod () {... }
```

Answer (score 1):

How about starting it with a `ServletContextListener`? Then it will be started as soon as your web application starts.

> void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) 
>             Receives notification that the web application initialization process is starting.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html

Also, about the scheduled task, you might want to consider options like these so you don't have to reinvent the wheel:

- http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html
- http://quartz-scheduler.org/

Cheers!